# Perform the same function on several arrays

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to scale several numpy arrays in the same way using `sklearn scalar` which has already been fit. How can I concisely transform all my arrays?

The following code does not modify the original arrays.

```
for X in [X_train_0, X_train1, X_train2, X_train3, X_test_n, X_test_0, X_test1, X_test2, X_test3]:
    X = scaler.transform(X)
```

Comment: `X[:] = scaler.transform(X)`, perhaps, I don't know.

Comment: @PeterWood Yup that the trick! Thanks

Comment: @PeterWood It is called slice assignment in Python.

Comment: @LiuXiMin yes, I just don't know anything about `scikit`, whether `transform` returns anything, or whether an `array` is the same as a `list`, etc. Usually I would go to the trouble of looking it up to check, but I'm busy so just put an answer I thought might work, with a proviso.